I want to schedule a script to run in Azure Data Factory, it has given that the pricing for 1000 run is 1$per month
I want to schedule a task/script that scrapes from the web pages using Azure data Factory, now in the official website has given that it costs around 1$ per 1000 runs, now in my case my scripts run only 3-4 times a month, now how the cost will be calculated on this situation.
I tried getting the cost from the official website and got the quotation as 1$ per 1000 runs but I want to know what will it costs if I ran only 3-4 runs per month.

From my understanding of Azure, the $1 per 1000 runs, will still be calculated at $1 regardless of how many runs you have in ran (if under 1000 runs). An inactive pipeline will be carted at $0.80 regardless. So if you do the math $0.80 is the charge just for the pipeline, where the $0.20 is what you get charged for the 1000 runs.
